# How do you create a "narrow by" filtering menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css

I would like to make a sidebar menu like mcmaster.com website. It allows you to dynamically narrow down the products and **toggle** through options. As you can see in the images, when "metric" option is selected all the page is changed based on metric based products, the sidebar and also the whole page. It is interesting that the URL has not been changed much. I mean the page is not being reloaded by clicking the "metric" option.
[before clicking the "metric" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYUuf.png)

[after clicking the "metric" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZrVs.png)

So, can I have somthing like this just with html, css and Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad. You would actually need to come up with the code and then post it in here in order to be helped by the community.

From what I see they use Ajax in order to update the page content based on the filter options.

A simples form of filtering would be if you have some items in the page already displaying and then, based on the filter, some would be shown and other would be hidden.

Below is a simple example. Blue is metric, green is inch. Also, if you click on clear you will clear the filtering. This is the most simple filter you can create.

```js
$(".filter span").click(function(){
  
  $(".filter span").removeClass("selected");
  
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  
  var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
  theClass = theClass.replace(" selected","");
  
  if ( theClass === "metric" ) {
    $(".items .inch").hide();
    $(".items .metric").show();
    } else if ( theClass === "inch" ){
      $(".items .inch").show();
      $(".items .metric").hide();
      
      } else {
        $(".item").show();
        $(".filter span").removeClass("selected");
        }
  
  });
```

```css
.filter {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left:
  }

.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  }

.items .inch {
  background: #0f0;
  }

.items .metric {
  background: #00f;
  }

.filter span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  }

.selected {
    font-weight: 900;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter">
  Choose: <span class="metric">metric</span> <span class="inch">inch</span><span class="clear"> clear</span>
  </div>
<ul class="items">
  
  <div class="item metric">1. metric</div>
  <div class="item inch">2. inch</div>
  <div class="item metric">3. metric</div>
  <div class="item metric">4. metric</div>
  <div class="item inch">5. inch</div>
  <div class="item metric">6. metric</div>
  <div class="item metric">7. metric</div>
  <div class="item inch">8. inch</div>
  <div class="item metric">9. metric</div>
  
  

  
  
  </ul>
```